Efficiently sorting 2D grid with only local operations
Suppose you have a n x m grid, and a pointer starting at (0,0), and the only operations you can do to the array, are:

Read the value of the current cell and the 4 cells around it (wrapping around the edges)
Move the pointer one space in a specified direction (wrapping around the edges)
Swap the values of the current cell with the one next to it in a specified direction (not wrapping around the edges)

What would be an efficient algorithm using these rules to move around the values such that every row and every column is individually sorted in ascending order?
E.g. if you started with the grid
4 5 2 2
1 3 6 4

some valid final arrangements would be
1 2 2 3
4 4 5 6

1 2 3 5
2 4 4 6

Edit: Here is an Insertion sort implementation of mine, which is quite bad...
Edit: It is clear that if you just sort each row individually, and then each column individually, you will reach a valid final arrangement. Here is a working implementation of everything needed for the below code, which uses insertion sort for each row and column. This then of course has time complexity of O(nm^2 + n^2m), since insertion sort is O(n^2) on an n element list.
def sort_row(direction):
    move(direction)
    for i in range(1, "length of grid in <direction>"):
        val = measure()
        k = i
        while k > 0 and measure(opposite(direction)) > val:
            swap(opposite(direction))
            move(opposite(direction))
            k -= 1
        for _ in range(k, i+1):
            move(direction)

def sort_all_rows(direction):
    for _ in range("length of grid in opposite of <direction>"):
        sort_row(direction)
        move(right(direction))

def sort_rows_then_cols():
    move_to(0, 0)
    sort_all_rows(East)
    sort_all_rows(North)

So if it was possible to sort each row individually in O(n logn) time, we could achieve a total time complexity of O(nm log(nm)) through this strategy, which I believe is the best possible. So my question boils down to: Is it possible to achieve better than quadratic time complexity for a single row?

You forgot to post your proposal for such an algorithm.

See here?

From How do I ask a good question?, in bold there: also copy the code into the question itself. Not repeated explicitly: User content lands in Creative Commons.

"It is clear that if you just sort each row individually, and then each column individually, you will reach a valid final arrangement." - I don't find that clear. Do you have a proof?

If each row is sorted, consider the ith column. If we sort this column, and some element ends up in the jth spot, it does so because there are (j-1) other elements in that column less than or equal to it. Now consider the original row for each of those j elements. Since those rows were sorted, we know that they all have corresponding elements in the (i-1) first columns, all less than or equal to it. Thus every column before this one contains at least j elements that are less or equal to our element, so sorting column (i-1) will leave a less or equal element in position j.

"So my question boils down to: Is it possible to achieve better than quadratic time complexity for a single row?" - When you can only swap neighbors? Does that mean you're looking for better analysis instead of a better algorithm? Like O(#inversions) instead of O(n^2)?
